How to add an external link to a bibliography item in AsciiDoc
Here below is my bibliography section:
[bibliography]
- [[[ref1, 1]]] Philippe Kruchten. link:https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~gregor/teaching/papers/4+1view-architecture.pdf[The “4+1” View Model of Software Architecture].
  Rational Software Corp. 1995.

It renders correctly... but the link doesn't work. If I hover the link, I see the URL above is appended to my document's URL. Am I missing something?

Yes, you don't need the link macro, as HTTP/S links are treated as macros.
This should work like you expect:
[bibliography]
- [[[ref1, 1]]] Philippe Kruchten. https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~gregor/teaching/papers/4+1view-architecture.pdf[The “4+1” View Model of Software Architecture].
  Rational Software Corp. 1995.

